# Scale down image when it doesn't fit on screen

Tags: android, imageview

I have this simple layout with image and text which are centered. I want text to be always visible and then use the rest of space for the image. The image should be scaled down if necessary. As you can see in the first image everything fits nicely in portrait mode but part of the image and part of the text are pushed out of the screen when in landscape mode. How can I fix this? I don't know the size of the image beforehand but I know my text is 54dp in height all the time. Also text must always be exactly below the image (no space between them). See the last image.

I guess it's impossible to do with XML alone and I will have to do some work on java side.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:src="@drawable/tree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="In May 2019, Italian broadcaster RAI announced that it had begun planning the 2020 edition of the Sanremo Music Festival. It was not confirmed whether the festival would be used to select Italy's participant for 2020."
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are not specifying the solution needed, do you need to scale it down how? This is too "tall", but what happens if it is too "fat"? I think the problem is: you are creating a problem. You should not use a LinearLayout if the height is gonna be undetermined, instead use a scroll view as root view.

Comment: @cutiko I don't want the view to be scrollable and I don't mind using any other container. My goal is to have the image scaled down when it doesn't fit the space provided.

Comment: I just saw your edit, will edit my answer.

Comment: you haven't answered the main question, what is the desired result? You add the examples for too small, but what about too big?

Comment: Check if my edit satisfies your requirements ;-)

Comment: Did you tried my latest edit?

Comment: @Racu, yes I did. I got strange result. See for yourself https://ibb.co/tJZTPm3

Comment: Changing `scaleType` to `centerCrop`, should make your image smaller, but according to your edits, you want to fit as much the screen as the image grows. Out of ideas, good luck.

Comment: @Racu thank you for your help. I'm assuming I have no other choice but to do the math and scale down the image myself on the java side.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that I came up. As soon as the views are drawn and their dimensions are known I recalculate the size of the `ImageView` taking into account the size of the image and the area available. See images below to understand how it works. I adjusted my layout a bit too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:text="In May 2019, Italian broadcaster RAI announced that it had begun planning the 2020 edition of the Sanremo Music Festival. It was not confirmed whether the festival would be used to select Italy's participant for 2020."
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tree)
        img.tag = R.drawable.tree
        img.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
    }

    private fun adjustImageViewSizeForImage(imgRes: Int) {
        val dimensions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        dimensions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, imgRes, dimensions)
        var imageViewWidth = dimensions.outWidth
        var imageViewHeight = dimensions.outHeight

        val availableWidth = (img.parent as ViewGroup).width
        val availableHeight = (img.parent as ViewGroup).height - text.height

        if (imageViewWidth > availableWidth) {
            val ratio = 1.0 * availableWidth / imageViewWidth
            imageViewWidth = availableWidth
            imageViewHeight = (ratio * imageViewHeight).toInt()
        }
        if (imageViewHeight > availableHeight) {
            val ratio = 1.0 * availableHeight / imageViewHeight
            imageViewHeight = availableHeight
            imageViewWidth = (ratio * imageViewWidth).toInt()
        }

        img.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageViewWidth, imageViewHeight)
    }

    private val onGlobalLayoutListener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            // view dimensions are known at this point
            img.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            adjustImageViewSizeForImage(img.tag as Int)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a new Resource layout file with the same file name, add qualifier orientation and select landscape. now you got two resources with same name one for default and other for landscape view.copy paste the same code there also, now you can see the landscape design preview there and just adjust your code fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution will be to replace your layout with [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

**Let me explain:**

You know that your textSize is `54dp`, but this is a fixed size and using it on your view will make your screen to be not responsive (this is because different phones got different screen size, and  `54dp` may look really small on large phones)

Sure, you can create one layout for every screen size but with `ConstraintLayout` you can create one responsive layout.

---

For your layout you can use **those attributes:**

- `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`
- `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent`

To manage the size of your views in percents relatively to the screen size.

**For example, this layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/rose"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:text="In May 2019, Italian broadcaster RAI announced that it had begun planning the 2020 edition of the Sanremo Music Festival. It was not confirmed whether the festival would be used to select Italy's participant for 2020."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the above layout, your textView height is equal to 15% of the screen in height.
Your textView and the image will keep this ratio for every screen size given.

**And the layout will look like this:**

[image]

### Extra information:

Now after you have the picture of your layout you must be wondering to yourself "why is my text being cut off, didn't he just mentioned how the layout is responsive?"

I did mentioned it, if you want your text to fit the screen as well you can use [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)